# How to change dropdown list selected value via cookies asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

In my Default.aspx I have a dropdown list that pulls indextypes from an Object Data source. Code Below

```
<h4>Index to search</h4>
<asp:DropDownList ID="dlSearchIndex" runat="server" CssClass="input-group " 
DataTextField="INDEX" DataValueField="INDEX" Width="150px" 
DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
SelectMethod="GetIndexType" TypeName="the.dll"> 
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I am trying to use cookies to set selectedvalue of this dropdown list like this:

```
If IsPostBack = False Then
        If Request.Cookies("IndexToSearch") IsNot Nothing Then
            dlSearchIndex.SelectedValue = 
            Request.Cookies("IndexToSearch").Value.ToString()
            Response.Cookies("IndexToSearch").Value = 
             dlSearchIndex.SelectedValue
            Response.Cookies("IndexToSearch").Expires = 
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)
        Else
            Response.Write("<p> No Cookie Found.</p>")
        End If
    End If
```

And I am creating the cookie like this:

```
If Request.Cookies("IndexToSearch") Is Nothing Then
            Dim cookie As New HttpCookie("IndexToSearch")
            cookie.Value = Trim(dlSearchIndex.SelectedValue)
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(350)
            Response.SetCookie(cookie)
            Response.Write("<p>" & cookie.Name & ":" & cookie.Value & ":")
        End If
```

The first time I run this code it works but after that I get this error:

```
"dlSearchIndex" has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not 
exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
```

Please, what am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can it be because the dropdown items are being pulled from a data source and not hard code

Comment: Is is possible that the client has cookies turned off?

Comment: I double checked and cookies are on, I have 2 Response.Writes that display the values of these cookies when I run the program but it just wont set the dropdownlist.selectedValue

Comment: Can you post the code that binds the data to the dropdown list?