# Dropdown List SelectedValue from cookie not working ASP.NET using vb

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I have a dropdown list that is populated from an object data-source (a query in one of my DLL's). I want to use cookies to have a selected value chosen in this list. I am doing it in the OnPreRendercomplete page event because that's the event after all databindings. I do not get errors but the dropdown list SelectedValue wouldn't change to the value of the cookie. Code Below:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRenderComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRenderComplete
        If IsPostBack = False Then
            If Request.Cookies("IndexToSearch") IsNot Nothing Then
                dlSearchIndex.SelectedValue = Request.Cookies("IndexToSearch").Value 
                txtBox1.Text = Request.Cookies("IndexToSearch").Value
                Response.Write("<p> Cookie Found.</p>" & Request.Cookies("IndexToSearch").Value)
                Response.Cookies("IndexToSearch").Value = dlSearchIndex.SelectedValue
                Response.Cookies("IndexToSearch").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60)
            Else
                Response.Write("<p> No Cookie Found.</p>")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

My cookies work properly because I use the value in it to populate a textbox which works fine `txtBox1.Text = Request.Cookies("IndexToSearch").Value`. Again, I don't get errors but the dropdown list does not update to the value of the cookie. What should I do? Do I have issues because it's from a data source? Thanks in advance!

This is different from other question because I am requesting, and responding the cookies in the page_OnPreRenderComplete event

[Image, Product, and Index to Search should match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYdqi.png)
[Code that creates the cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqAwe.png)

Comment: Did you try to delete the cookies?  The cookies get save from the response.  I suspect your  can't modify cookies to prevent hackers/viruses making changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change dropdown list selected value via cookies asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951367/how-to-change-dropdown-list-selected-value-via-cookies-asp-net)

Comment: @NoAlias previous question was mine as well Just asked it differently this time lol

Comment: @jdweng I set the cookies to expire in 60 seconds it gets deleted after that time right?

Comment: @BlackMarker Could you show us the data inside DropDownList and cookie value?

Comment: Yes the cookie will get deleted after 60 seconds.  And you can't modify a cookie that has been deleted.

Comment: @win I have attached an image. Textbox and selected value on the dl list is supposed to match

Comment: @jdweng in my onButton Click event I have an if statement that checks to see if there is a cookie then sets a cookie I will add an image for that too